# angular service not working as exp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, google-authentication

I am trying to put google login in a web app into an angular service, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my service

```
angular.module('sensdogserver.services', [])

.service('AuthenticationService', function ($window,$http) {
    console.log("service started")

    gapi.load('auth2', function() {//load in the auth2 api's, without it gapi.auth2 will be undefined

            gapi.auth2.init(
                    {
                        client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',

                    }
            );
    });


    this.googlelogin = function(){
        var GoogleAuth  = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        GoogleAuth.signIn().then(function(googleUser){//request to sign in
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

        username = profile.getName();
        $window.localStorage['username'] = username;
        googleUser = googleUser;
        googletoken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("google token: " + googletoken);
        $http.get("/api/auth/google/token",{headers:{'id_token':googletoken}}).success(function(data){console.log(data)}).error(function(data){console.log(data)});
        }

        )};


    this.googlesignout =function() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        console.log("signing out: ", username);
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        googleUser = null;
        googletoken = null;
        username = null;
          console.log('User signed out.');
        });
    }

    var googleUser = null;
    var googletoken = null;
    var username = null;

    this.googlelogin();


});
```

When I load the page, the console logs `service started` as expected, but then I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAuthInstance' of undefined`. If I comment out the call to google login and call `googlelogin` from a controller, after the page has loaded it works absolutely fine. What I don't understand is that I get the log message, so it seems the service is loaded and something runs, but not everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the `this.googlelogin();` call inside the `gapi.load('auth2', ...)` callback. You are calling it before it is initialized.

```
angular
  .module('sensdogserver.services', [])
  .service('AuthenticationService', function ($window,$http) {
    console.log("service started")

    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
      gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
      });
      console.log('gapi.load callback triggered');
      this.googlelogin(); // call it here in the load callback
    }.bind(this));

    this.googlelogin = function(){
      // ...
    };

    this.googlesignout = function() {
      // ...
    }

    // ...
    console.log('this will be printed before the gapi.load callback');
  });
```

I added logging to the load callback and to that place you used to call the `googlelogin` function to highlight the problem.

The `gapi.load()` call is asynchronous (non-blocking) - when you call it, it will call the desired API, but will not wait for the response. The response will be available in the callback function, which will be triggered in another event loop (after the main program block, where the `gapi.load()` function was called).

Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop, it should provide you with some basics about this. Calling `gapi.load` is very similar to the example with `setTimeout`.

Comment: It "magically" works, but it seems to me, that this is some of that async mystery that I don't understand very well (I hope yet...). So what happens here is that the thing is executed one after the other, but we do not wait on `gapi.load`, since it has a callback, so we pass it over and everything that depends on it should go into it's callback, right?

Comment: When you call `gapi.load(...)`, it will call the desired API, but will not wait for the response (so it is asynchronous, non-blocking). The response will be available in the callback function, which will be triggered in another event loop. Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop, it should provide you with some basics about this. Calling `gapi.load` is very similar to the example with `setTimeout`.